# Creating a custom CFType

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-foundation

Is it possible to create opaque types not derived from `CFTypeRef` which can be retained/released with `CFRetain`/`CFRelease`? Or how do I derive a new type from a `CFType`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CoreFoundation itself does not provide any such mechanism, but all Cocoa objects will work with CFRetain and CFRelease. So the only supported answer is: Create a class based on Foundation and CoreFoundation will recognize it as a CFTypeRef.

Comment: For now I use this for a "mixed" approach since the private API method is a little unsafe (and therefore will not make it to the AppStore). I only utilize the `init` and `dealloc` methods of a Cocoa class and make all instance variables public (interface is private, not in header). So it is pretty efficient because avoid all other message calls except `alloc`/`init`.

Comment: @Erik Aigner: It is actually not necessary to make all instance variables public. A neat little hidden feature of Objective-C is that functions defined inside a method implementation body get the same access to private state that an instance method would.

Answer (score 9):

I've never done this, but it is possible using private API. In all likelihood it will be dependent on a specific dot release of OS X, since the CF runtime could change from release to release.  In any case, CF is open source so I took a look at what [CFRuntime](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550.42/CFRuntime.h) does.  I was happy to see Apple included an example:

```
// ========================= EXAMPLE =========================

// Example: EXRange -- a "range" object, which keeps the starting
//       location and length of the range. ("EX" as in "EXample").

// ---- API ----

typedef const struct __EXRange * EXRangeRef;

CFTypeID EXRangeGetTypeID(void);

EXRangeRef EXRangeCreate(CFAllocatorRef allocator, uint32_t location, uint32_t length);

uint32_t EXRangeGetLocation(EXRangeRef rangeref);
uint32_t EXRangeGetLength(EXRangeRef rangeref);


// ---- implementation ----

#include <CoreFoundation/CFBase.h>
#include <CoreFoundation/CFString.h>

struct __EXRange {
    CFRuntimeBase _base;
    uint32_t _location;
    uint32_t _length;
};

static Boolean __EXRangeEqual(CFTypeRef cf1, CFTypeRef cf2) {
    EXRangeRef rangeref1 = (EXRangeRef)cf1;
    EXRangeRef rangeref2 = (EXRangeRef)cf2;
    if (rangeref1->_location != rangeref2->_location) return false;
    if (rangeref1->_length != rangeref2->_length) return false;
    return true;
}

static CFHashCode __EXRangeHash(CFTypeRef cf) {
    EXRangeRef rangeref = (EXRangeRef)cf;
    return (CFHashCode)(rangeref->_location + rangeref->_length);
}

static CFStringRef __EXRangeCopyFormattingDesc(CFTypeRef cf, CFDictionaryRef formatOpts) {
    EXRangeRef rangeref = (EXRangeRef)cf;
    return CFStringCreateWithFormat(CFGetAllocator(rangeref), formatOpts,
        CFSTR("[%u, %u)"),
        rangeref->_location,
        rangeref->_location + rangeref->_length);
}

static CFStringRef __EXRangeCopyDebugDesc(CFTypeRef cf) {
    EXRangeRef rangeref = (EXRangeRef)cf;
    return CFStringCreateWithFormat(CFGetAllocator(rangeref), NULL,
        CFSTR("<EXRange %p [%p]>{loc = %u, len = %u}"),
        rangeref,
        CFGetAllocator(rangeref),
        rangeref->_location,
        rangeref->_length);
}

static void __EXRangeEXRangeFinalize(CFTypeRef cf) {
    EXRangeRef rangeref = (EXRangeRef)cf;
    // nothing to finalize
}

static CFTypeID _kEXRangeID = _kCFRuntimeNotATypeID;

static CFRuntimeClass _kEXRangeClass = {0};

/* Something external to this file is assumed to call this
 * before the EXRange class is used.
 */
void __EXRangeClassInitialize(void) {
    _kEXRangeClass.version = 0;
    _kEXRangeClass.className = "EXRange";
    _kEXRangeClass.init = NULL;
    _kEXRangeClass.copy = NULL;
    _kEXRangeClass.finalize = __EXRangeEXRangeFinalize;
    _kEXRangeClass.equal = __EXRangeEqual;
    _kEXRangeClass.hash = __EXRangeHash;
    _kEXRangeClass.copyFormattingDesc = __EXRangeCopyFormattingDesc;
    _kEXRangeClass.copyDebugDesc = __EXRangeCopyDebugDesc;
    _kEXRangeID = _CFRuntimeRegisterClass((const CFRuntimeClass * const)&_kEXRangeClass);
}

CFTypeID EXRangeGetTypeID(void) {
    return _kEXRangeID;
}

EXRangeRef EXRangeCreate(CFAllocatorRef allocator, uint32_t location, uint32_t length) {
    struct __EXRange *newrange;
    uint32_t extra = sizeof(struct __EXRange) - sizeof(CFRuntimeBase);
    newrange = (struct __EXRange *)_CFRuntimeCreateInstance(allocator, _kEXRangeID, extra, NULL);
    if (NULL == newrange) {
    return NULL;
    }
    newrange->_location = location;
    newrange->_length = length;
    return (EXRangeRef)newrange;
}

uint32_t EXRangeGetLocation(EXRangeRef rangeref) {
    return rangeref->_location;
}

uint32_t EXRangeGetLength(EXRangeRef rangeref) {
    return rangeref->_length;
}

#endif
```

Comment: when I try to use the sample code, I get duplicate linker error on __EXRangeClassInitialize.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Richard This is code from CoreFoundation. Apple itself provides this example within the CF code itself, so you cannot use it in your code since you'd define the same object Apple has already defined. You need to use own names for your own objects.